# What can explain my port forwarding not working?

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding

I am trying to forward port 443 to a different server using iptables. What can explain this not working? I've enabled net.ipv4.ip_forward.

This is the code I use. I have no other iptables rules:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to 1.2.3.4:443
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 1.2.3.4 --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 2):

If your default forward policy is DROP then you also need to accept traffic to go back :

```
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -s 1.2.3.4 --sport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

You should secure this a little bit so if your box 1.2.3.4 is compromised at least no forged packet can go through your gateway using source port 443.

```
IPTABLES=/sbin/iptables
[ ... ]
$IPTABLES -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to 1.2.3.4:443
$IPTABLES -I FORWARD -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 1.2.3.4 --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -p tcp -s 1.2.3.4 --sport 443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```